# Quickblox one to one chat connection lost

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, quickblox

I have developed chat application using Quickblox SDK version 0.8.1. Sometimes app loses chat connection to the server so can not send message or receive message even in same chat page. I do have to reload every time this happens even sometimes it does not re-connect. So can any body help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reconnect to Chat please do:

**iOS way**

```
- (void)chatDidFailWithError:(int)code
{
    // reconnect
    [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:[LocalStorageController shared].qbUser];
}
```

**Android way (SDK 1.1 version)**

```
// initialize SMACK
SmackAndroid.init(this);

final QBUser user = new QBUser("garry", "garry2892pass");
user.setId(4234);
QBChatService.getInstance().loginWithUser(user, LoginActivity.this);


@Override
public void onLoginSuccess() {
    Log.d(TAG, "success when login");
}

@Override
public void onLoginError() {
    Log.e(TAG, "error when login");
}

@Override
public void onDisconnect() {
    Log.d(TAG, "disconnect when login");

    // Relogin here
}

@Override
public void onDisconnectOnError(Exception exc) {
    Log.e(TAG, "disconnect error when login", exc);

    // Relogin here
}
```

More info here http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

Just update Android SDK to 1.1 here  http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Download_Android_SDK

Comment: Hi! Thank you for response. Can you provide this code in Android, please? And also i am using version 0.8.1, so will this code work ?

Answer (score 2):

Use latest version of quickblox. Current version is 1.1.

You have to send presence after login with timeer according to this documentation. http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

After login

`QBChatService.getInstance().startAutoSendPresence(60);`

Hope this will solve.

Answer (score 1):

Use this way when using Quickblox SDK 2.0

```
ConnectionListener connectionListener = new ConnectionListener() {
@Override
public void connected(XMPPConnection connection) {

}

@Override
public void authenticated(XMPPConnection connection) {

}

@Override
public void connectionClosed() {

}

@Override
public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
    // connection closed on error. It will be established soon
}

@Override
public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {

}

@Override
public void reconnectionSuccessful() {

}

@Override
public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {

}
};



QBChatService.getInstance().addConnectionListener(connectionListener);
```